# In Firefox 13, how can I increase number of thumbnails in the new tab page?

Tags: firefox

In Firefox 13, the new tab page has 9 thumbnails which preview recently viewed sites.

How can I increase the number of thumbnails shown?

I tried in `about:config` and couldn't find a relevant entry. Google also turned up nothing relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [New Tab Tools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-tools/). It allows you to customize the number of thumbnails on new tab page.

Comment: +1 for a perfect and elegant solution. Thanks for this extension. It is not as heavy as Tab King and perfectly solves my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Increasing the number of thumbnails *isn't mentioned* in the Firefox 13 New Tab Page feature documentation

The [New Tab King extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-king/) does permit you to configure how many thumbnails you would like to view. The default is 3 rows of 4 but you can increase the number of rows.

[image: New Tab King - settings]

Comment: Thanks. It is a great extension. Roughly solves my problem.

Answer (score 4):

> I tried in about:config ...

The entries are under `browser.newtabpage` for the column and row integer values. Simply Right-click and choose modify for the new value.

```
browser.newtabpage.columns // int val
browser.newtabpage.rows    // int val
```

You can actually add something obscene like below (15*15)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Search the file `/usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja/chrome/browser/content/browser/newtab/newTab.xul`

Look for the lines with:

```
    <div id="newtab-grid">
      <div class="newtab-row">
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
      </div>
      <div class="newtab-row">
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
      </div>
      <div class="newtab-row">
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

For 4 thumbs per line, replace for:

```
    <div id="newtab-grid">
      <div class="newtab-row">
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
      </div>
      <div class="newtab-row">
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
      </div>
      <div class="newtab-row">
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

or add a

```
 <div class="newtab-cell"/>
```

line for each

```
 <div class="newtab-row">
```

block to get more thumbs per line. If you need some more rows, add an entire block

```
      <div class="newtab-row">
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
        <div class="newtab-cell"/>
      </div>
```

taking care to leave the same number of lines

```
  <div class="newtab-cell"/>
```

like the other blocks (for a complete matrix).

Comment: Dunno if Firefox has just changed over time or if this is a platform thing, but I can find no "newtab.xul" file nor any file (in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\) containing "newtab-cell".